# Centos and Fedora Docker, I can not start mysql

Tags: centos, docker, fedora, selinux, centos7

I am new on centos, I was in Ubuntu and my friend "yograterol convinced me to go over to Fedora was the best.

Change many things, the problem is that mysql does not start in docker, in my local fedora was the same, but in Docker did not work, no commands are:

```
# mysql 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Local fix it as follows:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0 
$ sudo service mysqld start
```

But in Docker, out the following:

```
# setenforce 0 
bash: setenforce: command not found 

# Service mysqld start 
bash: service: command not found
```

It happens in the Docker: Centos and Fedora.

I think it's because they are minimum operating system images.

Comment: nmap to Docker centos 3306/tcp closed mysql but in local 3306/tcp closed mysql

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running only `mysqld` ?

> [Invoke mysqld directly. This works on any platform.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-linuxunix-excerpt/5.0/en/automatic-start.html)